# Size of jTextfield not changing

Tags: java

I wrote the following code but the size of `jTextfield` is not changing. What should I do to change the size?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Window.*;
import java.text.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class One extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        int screenHeight;
        int screenWidth;
        public One() {
        initComponents();
        Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();



        screenHeight = screenSize.height;
        screenWidth = screenSize.width;


       jTextField2.setSize(screenHeight/50,screenWidth/40);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `setBounds(x,y,w,h)` method - `x` and `y` gives position for button and `w` and `h` gives width and height size of the content. For example:

```
JPanel jl=new JPanel();
L=new JButton("LOGIN"); 
jl.add(L);
L.setBounds(150, 50, 50, 20 );
```